# How can I join multiple tables having similar columns on sql server

Tags: sql-server, join, null

I tried joining 12 tables having similar columns but it brings out a more columns than expected while also having Null values.

```
SELECT *
FROM C1
FULL JOIN C2 ON C1.ID=C2.ID
FULL JOIN C3 ON C1.ID=C3.ID
FULL JOIN C4 ON C1.ID=C3.ID
```

When I tried this it brought out several columns having NULL values while also including the necessary values I wanted on the table joined

Comment: dont be lazy. Always select columns you need, not all of them. At least, you can always write SELECT C1.* FROM C1....

Comment: That's what a `FULL JOIN` does; it returns *all* the rows from the table, regardless of if related rows were found. What is the problem/question here?

Comment: I'm new to sql so what's the appropriate method I should use please

Comment: If would help to flesh out your question with some sample data and expected results. If you're only wanting a matching set of columns returned from all of the tables involved in the query then perhaps you're not wanting a `JOIN` at all but a `UNION`.

Comment: Query is behaving as expected..need more help post representative sample data and desired outcome as text

Comment: One usually combines FULL JOIN with a COALESCE function, where you take first not null column from your joined tables. Like: SELECT COALESCE(t1.col, t2.col, t3.col) etc

Comment: Look up LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN in the sql-server manual. Or queries and joining in general.